# What is the internet bandwidth requirement for audio video transmission in terms of quality HD video and Ultra sound with full duplex?

Tags: networking, video, internet, audio, bandwidth

Assume, i have a software project, which will allow desktop user to another desktop user communicate (peer to peer), desktop user to multiple users (peer to multi peer).

## Confuse:

If i use over internet audio/video transmission in full duplex, for peer to peer or peer to multiple peers.

A) Sender: What will be the exact bandwidth/speed requirements for sender ?. For sending and receiving audio in full duplex where, sample rate can be 8khz/16khz/32khz/44khz ?
- Receiver: same as sender

B) Sender: What bandwidth also will require while using HD video over internet in seperate calculation from audio point of view, is it much higher then audio transmission ?. 
- Receiver: same as sender
- Its very complex to find a correct speed/bandwidth requirement, for end user.

I also often get confused differences between internet speed and bandwidth like MBit vs MByte ???. What exactly i would need for those above two Mbit or Mbyte calculations ? 
Internet provides when say 512KB or 1MB upload/downlod speed available. What do they mean Bit or Byte per seconds ? Are those speed clear dedicated bandwidth or those are not transparent ?

I just want a best answer for this to make it very clear and transparent to me, before i start my project, its very confusing to me the internet bandwidth calculation in terms of HD video and Ultra sound transmission mathematics/formula.

I would really appreciate if someone, can explain this whole mystery point by point.

Many Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A) Sender: What will be the exact
>   bandwidth/speed requirements for
>   sender?. For sending and receiving
>   audio in full duplex where, sample
>   rate can be 8khz/16khz/32khz/44khz ? -
>   Receiver: same as sender

If you have peer to multipeer, you'll need the datastream * number of peers to send it to. So lets say you're transmitting to 23 peers at a datarate of 256 kbp/s. The sender then needs a speed of min. `23*256 = 5888 kbp/s`. The idea of peer to peer is that ever receiver is also a sender. In that case, you must also depend on the speed of your peers. The initial sender sends it to peer 1 and in turn peer 1 sends it to peer 2, etc. A combination is also possible, where peers aren't assigned to another but simply send to the ones that need the data.

For example Peer 1 recieves the data stream and sends it to Peer 2. Peer 2 wants to send it to Peer 3, but hasn't got enough bandwidth. Now Peer 1 has some bandwidth left so it aids Peer 2 and sends a part of the datastream directly to peer 3.

> B) Sender: What bandwidth also will
>   require while using HD video over
>   internet in seperate calculation from
>   audio point of view, is it much higher
>   then audio transmission ?. - Receiver:
>   same as sender - Its very complex to
>   find a correct speed/bandwidth
>   requirement, for end user.

Streaming true HD over the internet will be pretty hard since it WILL require a lot of bandwith. Sound takes a lot less data than video (especially HD video). Howmuch that is depends on how you encode your video and audio. Some encoding takes more data, depending on how heavy they compress data.

> I also often get confused differences
>   between internet speed and bandwidth
>   like MBit vs MByte ???. What exactly i
>   would need for those above two Mbit or
>   Mbyte calculations ? Internet provides
>   when say 512KB or 1MB upload/downlod
>   speed available. What do they mean Bit
>   or Byte per seconds ? Are those speed
>   clear dedicated bandwidth or those are
>   not transparent ?

There are basically 3 measures that are commonly used. Mbp/s MBp/s and MiBp/s. Mbp/s stands for Megabit per second, MBp/s stands for MegaByte per second and MiBp/s stands for MebiByte per second.

One byte consists of 8 bits (zeroes or ones). That means that 8 mbp/s is only 1 MBp/s. Then there's the MebiByte, which takes into account the correction for the fact that units of digital information are in powers of 2. One MebiByte for example is `2^10 = 1024` and not 1000.

For more information, I'd like to refer to the Wikipedia page here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_rate_units

Comment: Nice, it looks audio/networking is almost solved in this. Last question: Lets say video is used h264 or no compression because of highest quality for A to B. How it will be calculated (formula lets say to standardize it) resolution and frames or it has khz or it has size issues or pixels, how you know the bandwidth requirements. How do you measure that in terms of Bandwidth requirement and make a summary of total i need XXX upload/download for video part.

Comment: Please mind 8khz is not equal to 16khz or 32khz/44khz bandwidth. But how much bandwidth that sample rates cause ?

Comment: Assume, for another question related to networking, that i have, lets say you are in a (UK->London->Somewhere in Office) and you are using BT internet, and BT internet is also providing services to your next door offices. Are you going to get exact promised bandwidth ? IF they commited 1MBp/s for upload and download ?